# How do I select a table row with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, wikipedia

I'm having trouble scraping the rows from "[List of Nobel laureates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates)" in Nokogiri.

I believe my CSS selector is correct, but it's returning empty.

The original tutorial is "[Writing a Web Crawler](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/web-crawling/)".

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

BASE_WIKIPEDIA_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/'
LIST_URL = "#{BASE_WIKIPEDIA_URL}/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(LIST_URL))
rows = page.css('div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter tr')

puts "length : #{rows.size}"
```

Comment: what text you want to select? please mention.. I would like to test the CSS from my end.

Comment: well the first part of the tutorial is to extract each row first, from there it goes on (see linked tutorial) but I can't even do that currently. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You have a double slash in the URL you are building, so you're not actually looking at the page you think you're looking at. This is the URL you are using: [`http://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates`](http://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates), if you follow the link you'll see that it redirects to the Wikipedia homepage.
2. Your CSS selector is far too specific, and includes some information that won't be present in the raw page source. You should try a more simple selector:

   ```
   rows = page.css('table.wikitable tr')
   ```

   Specifically you are including the `jquery-tablesorter` class in your selector. This class is added by JavaScript, but the tools you're using don't execute the page's JavaScript, so the class won't be present and you can't use it to find table rows.

   If you use "view source", instead of the your browser's DOM inspector tool, you will see the raw source code without any JavaScript applied.

Comment: Good lesson for me.. :) How would you understand its added Jquery selector? clue please...

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm still not getting any results back.  Also how can I normally differentiate the additional Javascript portions of the selector (I'm using Chrome 'inspect element')?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how to see the raw source code.

Comment: in the words of homer j simpson, "DOH!". Thanks for catching my typo and giving the proper selector.  It does work.  But for future reference is there a cue I can follow to recognize those Javascript classes?

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you're expecting to a table with class jquery-tablesorter. That's because you're inspecting the table in your browser and it has that class. The problem is that jquery adds that class after the page loads. But since open-uri doesn't process javascript, that class never gets added to the table that nokogiri sees.

Long story short, you probably want to go with just:

```
page.css('table.wikitable tr')
```

Comment: My Editor is getting hanged... :(( Couldn't print the data.. What should I do? I am using *ST2*.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i'm still returning an empty result with that selector.  Also, how would I be able to distinguish the Javascript parts? (I assume they don't all start with jquery?)

Comment: Actually, they will all start with jquery.